# Unable to show all JSON response values in Collectionview(ERROR: Index out of range) in Swift

Tags: json, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am using collectionview in tableview cell.. here i want to show tableview cells one value in collectionview.. but all the time i am getting only one `filename` value even it has array of values

my JSON response in console:

```
JSON: {
result =     {
    bids =         (
                    {
         
            "get_attachments" =                 (
                                    {
                    filename = "1627385763-6142.png";
                },
                                    {
                    filename = "1627388474-7134.jpeg";
                },
                                    {
                    filename = "1627398168-8608.jpeg";
                }
            );
            "get_bid_user" =                 {
               
                fname = "new user";
                gender = M;
            };
        },
                    {
            "get_attachments" =                 (
                                    {
                                        
                    filename = "1627387642-9066.jpg";
                    
                }
            );
            "get_bid_user" =                 {
                fname = Akash;
                gender = M;
            };
        }
    );
```

**model for `JSON`**

```
public class ViewProposalResult {
public var bids : Array<Bid>?
}

public class Bid {

public var get_attachments : Array<Get_attachments>? 
 }

public class Get_attachments {
public var filename : String?
}
```

here i want `get_attachments` all `filename` values in collectionview.. how?

**for tableview and collectionview code:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewProposalTableVIewCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewProposalTableVIewCell


var bidData = viewproposalData?.result?.bids?[indexPath.row]

cell.bidAttatchment = bidData?.get_attachments

cell.attetchmentsCollectionview.reloadData()
return cell
}

//collectionview code
class ViewProposalTableVIewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var attetchmentsCollectionview: UICollectionView!

public var bidAttatchment: Array<Get_attachments>?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return bidAttatchment?[section].filename?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BidAttatchmentCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BidAttatchmentCollectionViewCell

    var attatchBid = bidAttatchment?[indexPath.item]//getting error "Index out of range:"
    cell.attatchmentLbl.text = attatchBid?.filename
    
    
    return cell
}
```

error:

> Fatal error: Index out of range

where am i wrong. please do guide me

Comment: You have `bidAttatchment?[section].filename?.count ?? 0` and use `bidAttatchment?[indexPath.item]`. That's seems "contradictory" to use `section` and `item` for the "index" logic, no?

Comment: @Larme, yes you are correct.. but if i change `var attatchBid = bidAttatchment?[indexPath.section]
        cell.attatchmentLbl.text = attatchBid?.filename` then it showing only first `1627385763-6142.png` 19 times in tableview first row and `1627387642-9066.jpg` 19 times in tableview second row... but i got response like above.. in 1st row 3 filenames and in 2nd row 1 filename

Comment: @Larme please do guide

Comment: So maybe `bidAttatchment?[section].filename?.count ?? 0` was totally wrong then? From what I guess with the naming of the variables, but you are saying that in each section, you want `n` items where `n` is the number of characters in `filename`, does it make sense to you? Did you meant instead: return `bidAttatchment?.count ?? 0`, and `var attatchBid = bidAttatchment?[indexPath.item]`?

Comment: @Larme hmm ur right.. thank you. i was totally confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all consolidate the naming of the variables to make clearer what is a single object and what is an array.

- Replace `bidAttatchment` with `attachments` (plural form)
- Replace `Get_attachments` with `Attachment` (singular form)
- Declare the array as non-optional empty array. The benefit is you get rid of all the question marks

Then in `numberOfItemsInSection` just return the number of items in `attachments`. Your data source doesn't contain sections so the `section` parameter is irrelevant.

```
class ViewProposalTableVIewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var attetchmentsCollectionview: UICollectionView!
    
    public var attachments = Array<Attachment>()
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return attachments.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BidAttatchmentCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BidAttatchmentCollectionViewCell
    
        let attatchBid = attachments[indexPath.item]
        cell.attatchmentLbl.text = attatchBid.filename
        
        return cell
    }
```